# How to set a comma sep. string as a paramter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get query string values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

ive a a function call like:

```
var ex = _.where(obj, {param1:0,param2:1});
```

which works fine, all the code behind.

I check my URL and take out the parameters and save this information into a array:

```
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);

    var vars = query.split("&");

    var testParamter = vars.toString().replace( /=/g,':' );
```

that return by using console.log(testParamter); the following result:

```
param1:0,param2:1
```

but i cant insert yet the var testParamter into my function call:

```
var ex = _.where(obj, {testParamter});
```

because it is a string and i cant handel it with eval(). so can anyone tell me please the right way to solve it?

thanks

Comment: You've got a [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). See duplicate [How can I get query string values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Comment: What do you want testParamter to be?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the values from the querystring and create an object from those values :

```
var query  = window.location.search.substring(1),
    vars   = query.split("&"),
    params = {};

$.each(vars, function(k,v) {
    var arr = v.split('=');
    params[ decode(arr[0]) ] = decode(arr[1]);
});

var ex = _.where(obj, params);

function decode(s) { 
    return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(/\+/g, " ")); 
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to [decode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2880929/1048572) the parameter name and value.

Comment: @Bergi - Sounds like a good idea, and nice link! Don't want to copy the answer, and the link is there for anyone interested, but I'll add the decodeURI without the regex replace etc.

Comment: The replacing of `+` with spaces is quite importand, I'd say.

Comment: hmm thanks a lot but the issue remains. if i print the params.toSource() i see double qoutes around the values. this is not accepted by the underscore.js ._where() function so i try in the each to remove the qoutes with no effect. if i inser these key/value pair directly everthings works.